# Possible to adjust color of font for front page questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, design

When I load the front page of C.SE, the questions that have been read are in one shade of blue, and any questions that haven't are in another, similar shade of blue. Depending on the lighting and the contrast settings on the monitor, sometimes the two shades are nearly indistinguishable.

On meta, questions show up as either black, or a shade of beige.

Is there a way for users to adjust the colors of the front page questions on C.SE so that they are more easily distinguishable?

Comment: This theme is common to all beta sites, I'll make sure this gets seen by someone from SEI.

Comment: FYI: I haven't heard back about a [similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126962/1438).